# Search result in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I want result like suppose i have 3 products with their name like sony tv, led tv and led test Tv. so if I search only by name Tv then all products should be display and other condition if i search test Tv then it should only disply (led test Tv) not other results.

Answer (score 1):

open your cms,

click system -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog search -> change your Search Type to full text.

after that you'll be notified  to reindex your search then you have to reindex it.

Comment: Not working like that suppose i have text like ruff tutu pro and  tutu test pro and if i search tutu pro then it should result me only ruff tutu pro.